# Is it possible to travel with both travel document and home country passport?

Tags: canada

I have a Canada RTD and my home country passport. I travelled from Canada to Georgia with my RTD. I entered Georgia with my RTD too. Now I'm planning to travel to a visa-free country, which doesn't request visa from my home country passport.

I need to obtain a visa for my RTD. The question is, can I travel to that country with my home country passport? When I pass passport control, do I need to use and show my RDT or home country passport? I have to use my home passport because Canada shouldn't know about this travel.

Comment: If Canada shouldn't know about this travel because you might lose your refugee status then you should be talking to a lawyer, not random strangers on the internet.

Comment: @S. Demirdoven Is your profile name your real name? Also not a good idea on an Internet forum

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be asking for advice about breaking the law.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's almost certain that the country you are visiting does not care whether you have a Refugee Travel Document and/or a passport from your home country. It will have no trouble accepting your passport and granting you a visit.

The issue comes with the way Canada will view this. You have been granted refugee status because you told the Canadian authorities that you face persecution in your home country, and implicitly that the government is part of that. If you use your home country passport, you are in effect saying that you are willing to put yourself under the protection of your home country, which is not consistent with your facing government persecution. It looks as if you lied to them in your refugee application.

Because of this **if you use your home country passport at all there is a likelihood that your refugee status may be revoked**. This is in additional to any consequences of the travel, which you have already stated "Canada shouldn't know about", and which probably carries similar consequences. Revocation is not always applied, but you should definitely check with a bona fide lawyer with expertize in the area who can tell you the likely consequences.

Comment: @S.Demirdoven: None that appears to affect the applicability of DJClayworth's advice. Especially his last sentence.

Comment: If you use your home country passport AT ALL you run the risk of the possible consequences I mentioned.